# MYSQL - Concatenate two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, concatenation

I have two tables as follows:

```
    TABLE A                    TABLE B
 StuID | actid              FacID | actid
  3       12                  98      17
  5       17                  54      21
```

I want to list the name of everyone, both students and faculty, who participate in activity 17. Is there anyway I can get a result as below:

```
 id  | actid
 98     17
 5      17
```

WITHOUT creating a new table (by just using nesting of expressions or derived relations) ?

A JOIN on the actid would give something like:

```
StuID  | FacID  | actid
 5        98        17
```

I guess I need a form of concatenation??

Comment: This form of concatenation is called a UNION in SQL, and Thilo has the correct answer, below (you should accept that answer so Thilo gets credit).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
select * from table_a where actid = 17
union all
select * from table_b where actid = 17
```

You may (or may not) need to do something about the ids not being unique, such as

```
select 'Student', table_a.* from table_a where actid = 17
union all
select 'Faculty', table_b.* from table_b where actid = 17
```

Comment: I've had to wrap each SELECT in () for MySQL to be happy.

Answer (score 1):

You want UNION ALL:

(SELECT * FROM tablea) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM tableb)

I think those parenthese are correct.  I remember MySQL being fussy about this.

Comment: parenthesis should not be required, at least, spec is nor requiring it I believe

Answer (score -2):

its too easy 
`select tableA.stuId,tableA.actId, tableB.facId,tableB.actId` 
 from tableA,tableB
 where tableA.actid=tableB.actid;`

Comment: join is concatenating columns, this question was about concatenating rows

Answer (score -6):

You can concatenate these two tables by using `select`, `from` and `where`.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. SELECT FROM and WHERE are too generic to be marked as a helpful answer.