# Merge two database into a single database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bulkinsert

I have two dump of same  database from different mysql servers. i need to combine these two dumps into a single database automatically by adjusting the primary keys and foreign keys.
 For example consider two sql dumps say mysqldump1 and mysqldump2 which contains two tables country_table and child_table. Here follows the data of two dumps
**Dump: mysqldump1.dmp**
**Table1: country_table**

```
+----+-------------------+
| id |    Country        |
+----+-------------------|
|  1 |  India            |
|  2 |  China            |
|  3 |  USA              |
|  4 |  England          |
|  5 |  Iran             |
+----+-------------------+
```

**Table2: person_table**

```
+----+-------------------+-------------+
| id |    Name           | Country (fk)|
+----+-------------------|-------------|
|  1 |  Tom              |     1       |
|  2 |  Anish            |     2       |
|  3 |  James            |     2       |
|  4 |  Akhil            |     5       |
|  5 |  Jobi             |     4       |
+----+-------------------+-------------+
```

**Dump: mysqldump2.dmp**
**Table1: country_table**

```
+----+-------------------+
| id |    Country        |
+----+-------------------|
|  1 |  Dubai            |
|  2 |  Australia        |
+----+-------------------+
```

**Table2: person_table**

```
+----+-------------------+-------------+
| id |    Name           | Country (fk)|
+----+-------------------|-------------|
|  1 |  Binu             |     1       |
|  2 |  Justin           |     2       |
|  3 |  Mark             |     2       |
+----+-------------------+-------------+
```

The result database contains contains entries combination of two dumps which looks like follows. Please note that the result database which contains the combination of above two databases which adjusts the primary and foreign keys

**Result Database**
**country_table**

```
+----+-------------------+
| id |    Country        |
+----+-------------------|
|  1 |  India            |
|  2 |  China            |
|  3 |  USA              |
|  4 |  England          |
|  5 |  Iran             |
|  6 |  Dubai            |
|  7 |  Australia        |
+----+-------------------+
```

**person_table**

```
+----+-------------------+-------------+
| id |    Name           | Country (fk)|
+----+-------------------|-------------|
|  1 |  Tom              |     1       |
|  2 |  Anish            |     2       |
|  3 |  James            |     2       |
|  4 |  Akhil            |     5       |
|  5 |  Jobi             |     4       |
|  6 |  Binu             |     6       |
|  7 |  Justin           |     7       |
|  8 |  Mark             |     7       |
+----+-------------------+-------------+
```

Can you please suggest me an idea to merge two database into single database which looks like above. (I am using mysql database)

Comment: i need to merge two databases. But database contains two tables only

Answer (score -1):

Export each table to CSV, then import them into the merged database. Once you have all the tables in the same database you can write SQL to append the data.

See [MYSQL - Concatenate two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974185/mysql-concatenate-two-tables) for more details about the concatenating part.

The trick is to get them in the same database first.

Comment: Is it adjust the foreign key too?

Comment: U haven't supplied enough info for me to help with that. If you are adding records then yes it should maintain the foreign key constraint unless the DB is's have duplicate primaries