# SQL query for combining data from two tables

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I would like to combine data from two different tables that have no actual realationship between each other, thus I cannot use JOIN. The tables' structure is as it follows:

ice_creams

- total
- advertiser
- provider
- supplier

snacks

- total
- advertiser
- provider
- supplier

I would like to run a query that results in a table with:
ice_creams_total, snacks_total, advertiser, provider, supplier

I can achieve that for each table separately by running:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS ice_creams_total,
       advertiser AS "advertiser::filter",
       provider AS "provider::filter",
       supplier AS "supplier::multi-filter"
FROM ice_creams
WHERE time >= now() - toIntervalHour(96)
GROUP BY integration_id,
         advertiser,
         provider,
         supplier
ORDER BY integration_id ASC,
    ice_creams_total DESC
```

Can I achieve doing this for both tables, combining the results?

Comment: Well... there are three relationships rigth there: advertiser, provider, supplier.

Comment: What's that `integration_id`? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all`.  Here is one way:

```
SELECT SUM(ice_cream_total) AS ice_creams_total,
       SUM(snaks_total) as snacks_total,
       advertiser AS "advertiser::filter", provider AS "provider::filter", supplier AS "supplier::multi-filter"
FROM ((SELECT ice_cream_total, 0 as snacks_total, integration_id, advertiser, provider, supplier
       FROM ice_creams ic
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 0, total, integration_id, advertiser, provider, supplier
       FROM snacks s
      )
     ) x
WHERE time >= now() - toIntervalHour(96)
GROUP BY integration_id, advertiser, provider, supplier
ORDER BY integration_id ASC, ice_creams_total DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the results of 2 queries using `union all`, provided the SELECT columns match. Therefore consider changing the name `ice_creams_total` to `total` (likewise `snacks_total` to `total`) and add an extra manual field to 2 queries, `type`.
eg.

```
SELECT 'ice_creams' type,
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'snacks' type,
...
```

see more: [MYSQL - Concatenate two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974185/mysql-concatenate-two-tables)
see also: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php